# How to open file explorer and highlight file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

I'm developing a flutter desktop app, currently my solution is use `url_launcher`, but it only does open folder, not support highlight file, is there similar to electron e.g `shell.showItemInFolder('filepath')` in flutter?

Link：https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100361#issuecomment-1072303822

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can write cmd line through your dart code
ex: if you have file located at D:\test\test\text.txt your dart code will be
Process.run('explorer.exe ', [
'/select,',
'D:\test\test\text.txt',
]);

Comment: That not support all platform.